# FindBugs Does Not Show Up in Project Properties

Tags: eclipse, plugins, findbugs

I had just installed FindBugs plugin for Eclipse. My Eclipse is Juno. I am using Windows 7.

It shows up at Help -> about Eclipse -> Installed Software as FindBugs Feature

However it does not exist on Project Properties.

I had tried to run eclipse as Administrator, installing from either marketplace or manual.

But no luck.

I use a copied Eclipse (without installation) at Desktop.

Any thought on how to shows the FindBugs in project properties?

Thanks

Answer (score 22):

Just in case you haven't figured out yet, and so it might help others like me.
If you are installing a version of Eclipse FindBugs 3.0 or greater, then it's only supported on Java 7.
Update your JDK to 7.0 and you will see Findbugs show up as a part of your properties. Wasted a lot of hours on this one.

Comment: I had the exact same issue. Thanks @Preethi

Comment: THANKSSSSSS. This not only made find bugs to work, but also a number of other plugins which I installed but gave up on them because they were not showing up anywhere in the menu. Wish I could upvote 10000 times.

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem. I am using Kepler + windows 7 + jdk1.5. This got resolved with jdk update from 1.5 to 1.7. 
May be it has dependency on 1.7 but there was no error message and like you said it was not visible in preference.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this tutorial:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Findbugs/article.html

I am using Eclipse Kepler in Windows 7, but it shouldn't make any difference.

There is also a FindBugs entry in context menu (right click project, under Import and Export options, in my case)

Answer (score 1):

Edit your eclipse.ini file (you can find it in your eclipse installation folder) and change or add (if it does not exist) the -vm parameter value to a Java 7 JDK. More info [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini).

Answer (score 1):

All other answers (installing latest Java, Eclipse update, adding '-vm ...' to the .ini-file did not work for me.
I solved it by clicking "Window"->"Perspective"->"Open Perspective"->"Other..."->"FindBugs".

Then switch back to 'Java'-perspective. Now the menu is available when you right-click the project.